# Apache vhost-specific logging

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, mod-security

I have the following apache setting  (in `conf.d/owasp-modsecurity.conf`):

```
SecAuditLog "/var/www/vhosts/${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}}/statistics/logs/modsec_audit.log"
```

When I do `httpd -t` I get the following error:

> Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/owasp-modsecurity.conf:
>   ModSecurity: Failed to open the audit log file: /var/www/vhosts/${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}}/statistics/logs/modsec_audit.log

My intention should be reasonably obvious; I want mod_security audit log entries to end up in vhost-specific files.
This already happens with regular access and error logs (though I've no idea how it is done).

For the record, I also tried the following entries blindly, none worked: `$HOSTNAME` `${SERVER_NAME}` `$SERVER_NAME` and `$HOST`.

On a second though, these are environment variables...shouldn't there be something to get Apache internal variables instead?

**Related links**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684655/is-it-possible-to-use-variables-in-httpd-conf
- [Per-user vhost logging](https://serverfault.com/questions/441421/per-user-vhost-logging)

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the SecAuditLog entry into the setting for each of your virtual hosts.

Something like this (setup can look a little bit different but this is a basic setting). <strike>Also you could check your other log entries (CustomLog, ErrorLog etc) for possible wildcards to insert.</strike>

```
domain1.conf
============
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin postmaster@domain1.com
  ServerName www.domain1.com

  SecAuditLog "/var/www/vhosts/domain1/statistics/logs/modsec_audit.log"
  # lots of more setting goes here
  # ...
</VirtualHost>

domain2.conf
============
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin postmaster@domain2.com
  ServerName www.domain2.com

  SecAuditLog "/var/www/vhosts/domain2/statistics/logs/modsec_audit.log"
  # lots of more setting goes here
  # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and clarification on wildcards. I was unsure about the wildcards - I've always worked with static log files myself

Comment: @Jensd I don't know how the other log files work because they're done through Plesk. I can't go with the `<VirtualHost>` way because it would mean having to do this change manually each time a new domain is added.

Comment: @JennyD That point is not really feasible - the file is created only once (the first request) and opened when necessary (as is always the case).

Comment: Do you add domains very often? Perhaps you can edit some kind of virtualhost-template in the Plesk setup?

Comment: @Jensd That's a possibility. My problem is that there are other people that may add domains.